# IIS7 with SSL certification and virtual directories

Tags: security, ssl

I tried to find something that answers this question directly, but nothing is clear.

I have a domain name say `www.domain.com` in the domain I have virtual directories:

`www.domain.com/directory1` and `www.domain.com/directory2`. what type of SSL certificate do I need to make both directories and their content secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. there are no restrictions whether to use the cheapest or more expensive certificate.

Fabio

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about installing two different SSL certs in the virtual directories?

I'm afraid if that is what you are looking for.. then is not possible.

SSL certs are bind to website level not virtual directory, so you need to install the cert at the website and then configure whether to force SSL on any desired virtual directories.

Fabio
@fcerullo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No I want one cert, but can I just use the cheapest cert? it's for a couple of web services to sit behind in the virtual directories.